# HTML5 Canvas smooth scroll tilemap

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

I've tried to build a scrollable tilemap with the canvas object which automatically calculates it's size relative to the screen resolution and renders the tiles relative to a position on a (bigger) map.

I planned to move the generated tiles and only draw the tiles that need to be drawn new.

So that means I scroll the map, draw the new tiles at the top (for example on moving upwards) and deleting the last tiles on the botton which are now out of the visible canvas.

**My problem is:**

I don't think that it's very good for the performance to change the position of every tile in the canvas, I think this could be solved using `getImageData()` and `putImageData()` but there is still one problem left:

If i just move these tiles and draw new tiles it will always "hop" for 30px (1 tile = 30x30), so is there a simple / performance technically good way to make this with a smooth, linear scroll effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fill the board wither using `drawImage` or pattern (the latter require you to use translate to get the tiles in the right position).

drawImage takes new destination size as argument so you can zoom the tiles too.

Here is a pattern implementation I made for some other question, but I assume you should be able to see what goes on in the code:

```
function fillPattern(img, w, h) {

    //draw the tile once
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    /// draw horizontal line by cloning
    /// already drawn tiles before it
    while (w < canvas.width) {
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, w, 0);
        w *= 2;
    }

    /// clone vertically, double steps each time
    while (h < canvas.height) {
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, h);
        h *= 2;
    }
}
```

The performance is good as you can see in the **[implementation this was used for](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/kPm4k/)** (video wall with live scaling and tiling).

To project this more to what you have - instead of drawing each tile as above you can simply draw the canvas to a new position and fill in the new "gap":

```
ctx.drawImage(myCanvas, offsetX, offseY);
fillGap();
```

You could have used clipping with drawImage but the canvas will clip this for new internally so there is no gain in clipping the image in JavaScript as you move part of it outside the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful text! My grid is textured so I can't just copy the rows, I have to load the texture ID for every field from a database and I'm currently searching a way to improve that 'cause I think it's not really fast. The idea with moving the canvas and filling the gap really helped me but is there a way to do the same thing with a linear animation? Or is this only possible by doing this 30 times /s so that it looks like an animation?

Comment: @cybrox there is unfortunately no away around drawing it x times seconds. This is how system does it at low-level and also how video players does it. Apropos video: the option here is to pre-render everything but it has its cost too such as memory and initial loading time. You can also pre-render tiles that are grouped or doesn't change as well as pre-render a larger area to an off-screen canvas and make sort of a cache (related to double-buffering). Using 2 canvases may also be beneficial where you have the moving background on one bottom canvas and the static/different animation on the top.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
I'm currently using multiple canvas', one for the tiles and one for the objects on it. The tiles are stored in tilesets to reduce the amount of images to load drastically, there are always 10x10 tiles (= 300x300 px) packed in one tileset and only a part of the whole image is rendered as a single tile in the canvas. However, thanks for your help, I'll try to get into calculating everything relative to a given FPS rate and make it appear smooth :)